# How can I make my navbar toggler only appear when the screen hits a sm breakpoint?

Tags: bootstrap-4, styling

I cant seem to get the toggler to only appear at a sm breakpoint. Can someone please point out my error? I am trying to get it to display my logo, Home, Our apps and then the drop down more until it reaches a mobile screen where its just plain hamburger.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="/Assets/LOGO.png" width="300" height="150" alt=""></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Our Apps</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          More
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=5447356877511937129">Google Play</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVC1atDAYpvoHfTDjUij1PA">YouTube</a></li>
          <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.facebook.com/dyoll.lang">Facebook</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer I was missing a breakpoint in my opening navbar tab

needed

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-md">
```

vs

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
```